# $\lim_{n \in \mathbb{N}}n\cdot\mathrm{e}^{1/n} - n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If I replace $\newcommand{\euler}{\mathrm{e}}$$n \to x$ where $x$ is a continuous variable. Then, I can easily apply L'Hopital's rule to $\frac{\euler^{1/x} - 1}{1/x}$ to get that the limit is $1$.

I don't know if this is legal? Is it?

There is a corresponding  [L'Hopital's rule for sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). But I have not had success in applying that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the maneuver is legal, but it's worth elaborating the relationship between limits of discrete and continuous functions extending them.

If, given a function $g : \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ and a continuous function $\tilde g : \Bbb R^+ \to \Bbb R$ satisfying $\tilde g\vert_\Bbb N = g$, even the existence of the limit $\lim_{t \to \infty} \tilde g (t)$ is a priori possibly a stronger statement than $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)$.

For example, the function $\tilde g(x) = \sin 2 \pi x$ restricts to $g(n) = 0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = 0$ whereas $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ does not exist. However, one can show that the converse statement holds: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \tilde g(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n)$ exists and $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(n) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \tilde g(x)$.

Fortunately, this is the direction your argument uses: The function $x \mapsto x (e^{1 / x} - 1)$ on $\Bbb R^+$ restricts to the function $n \mapsto n (e^{1 / n} - 1)$ on $\Bbb N$. Since you can show that the limit of the former as $x \to \infty$ exists and compute it, the limit of the latter exists and its value coincides with it.

**Remark** This method relies the same underlying principle as l'Hopital's Rule, but another way to think about the problem is to expand $n (e^{1 / n} - 1)$ in a series at infinity: Since $$e^{1 / n} \sim 1 + \frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$
we have
$$e^{1 / n} - 1 \sim \frac{1}{n} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),$$
and thus
$$n (e^{1 / n} - 1) \sim 1 + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right),$$
so, just as you found using l'Hopital's Rule,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n (e^{1 / n} - 1) = 1 .$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$

> We know that $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)=L$ if and only if ,for every sequence $x_n \to x_0$ ,we have $f(x_n) \to L$ as $n \to +\infty$

For $f(x)= \frac{e^x-1}{x}$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $x_0=0$ we have  that the limit is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}e^x=e^x$, the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says
$$
\frac{e^{1/n}-e^0}{1/n-0}=e^{\xi}
$$
for some $\xi\in(0,1/n)$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{1/n}-1}{1/n}
&=\lim_{\xi\to0^+}e^{\xi}\\[6pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: for any $z>0$ we have

$$ \frac{e^z-1}{z} = \frac{1}{z}\int_{0}^{z}e^t\,dt, $$
i.e. the LHS is the mean value of $e^t$ over $[0,z]$. Due to the continuity of the exponential function
$$ \lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{e^z-1}{z} = e^0 = 1, $$
and by considering the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$, convergent to $0$, we get
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(e^{1/n}-1\right) = e^0 = 1.$$